# The Jquery image slider doesn't work in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

I added a Jquery image slider to my website. But it doesn't work on Google Chrome. It works perfectly in Firefox. Any idea why? The site url : http://lit-falls-8182.herokuapp.com/

Can you see the last image smaller than the rest? and all the images disappear and never come back. It need to loop.

HTML code :

```
<div id="scroller" >
          <div class="innerScrollArea">
              <ul>
            <% @slideimages.each do |simage| %>
               <li><%= image_tag simage.gsub("app/assets/images/", ""), alt: "Slide Image", class: "slide-image" %></li>
            <% end %>
              </ul>
          </div>
     </div>
```

Css code :

```
#scroller {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #FF9500;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 20px #C4C4C4;
    height: 160px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 19;

    .innerScrollArea {
        overflow: hidden;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
    }

    ul {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        position: relative;
    }

    li {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        list-style-type: none;
        position: absolute;
    }

    .slide-image{
        z-index: 1;
        padding: 2px;
        display: block;
        opacity:0.8;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
     -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
       -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
      -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
          transition: all 0.5s ease;
        &:hover {
            z-index: 2;
            border: 2px solid #FF9500;
            transform: scale(1.1);
            opacity:1;
            padding: 0px;
        }

    }

}
```

Javascript code :

```
$(function(){
    var scroller = $('#scroller div.innerScrollArea');
    var scrollerContent = scroller.children('ul');
    scrollerContent.children().clone().appendTo(scrollerContent);
    var curX = 0;
    scrollerContent.children().each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.css('left', curX);
        curX += 224;
    });
    var fullW = curX / 2;
    var viewportW = scroller.width();

    // Scrolling speed management
    var controller = {curSpeed:0, fullSpeed:1};
    var $controller = $(controller);
    var tweenToNewSpeed = function(newSpeed, duration)
    {
        if (duration === undefined)
            duration = 600;
        $controller.stop(true).animate({curSpeed:newSpeed}, duration);
    };

    // Pause on hover
    scroller.hover(function(){
        tweenToNewSpeed(0);
    }, function(){
        tweenToNewSpeed(controller.fullSpeed);
    });

    // Scrolling management; start the automatical scrolling
    var doScroll = function()
    {
        var curX = scroller.scrollLeft();
        var newX = curX + controller.curSpeed;
        if (newX > fullW*2 - viewportW)
            newX -= fullW;
        scroller.scrollLeft(newX);
    };
    setInterval(doScroll, 20);
    tweenToNewSpeed(controller.fullSpeed);
});
```

Comment: it working in my chorme

Comment: working fine in chrome for me. cntrl+f5 maybe ?

Comment: Try disabling extensions and see if that clears the problem.

Comment: Can you see the last image smaller than the rest? and all the images disappear and never come back. It need to loop.

Comment: @Bryan doesn't work :( Can you see all the images in the same size?

Comment: @Riturajratan can you see a never ending scroller or does it stop when all the images are gone? It should repeat the images ... should loop

Comment: @Barmar even tried in a different machine. Does it work exactly as in Firefox?

Comment: You're right, it works differently in Chrome than FF. But if you want help, you need to post your slider code. The page you linked to just has a huge, minified Javascript file. You don't expect us to debug that for you, do you?

Comment: @Barmar Oh please forgive me for my foolish mistake. I forgot that Rails compile the script files before uploading them to the server :) I have posted the code. Please check :)

Comment: Your CSS doesn't look valid, you have style blocks inside other style blocks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your css file you have this bit of code:

```
img{
  max-width:100%;
  height:auto
}
```

Remove `max-width:100%;` to fix both of your problems.

Answer (score 0):

I see your issue in Chrome, but I tried to replicate it on my system by pulling your scripts and it's not the same.

Having said that, you can see if you 'Inspect Element' that the images are there but just progressively smaller after the ones that show on the screen until they can't be seen. It could be related to screen size (which is why most commenters can't see it)

I'd try adding an explicit image size to the img tags `width='220' height='165'` or setting it in the javascript (jQuery) with something like:

```
$(".slide-image").width(220);
$(".slide-image").height(165);
```

before, during and/or after the scroll.